# Reading mails over POP3 in Gmail through java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Good evening SO

I'm trying to make wonderful piece of code that can retrieve message over the POP protocol. I've so far followed the [RFC1939](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt) (POP Specification).

And actually it's working with my web host's POP3 server (which is not over SSL).But when accessing GMail all I get is empty responses :(

I assume it's the SSL part that's "breaking" it.

In my "open" function that creates the Socket I have this:

```
public void open() throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
    if(this.SSL)
    {
        SSLSocketFactory fac = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        this.s = fac.createSocket(this.in_host, this.in_port);
    }
    else
    {
        this.s = new Socket(this.in_host, this.in_port);
    }

    this.out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
}
```

where `SSL` is a bool indicating the connection should be over SSL, and `s` is the Socket. `in_host` and `in_port` is the host (pop.gmail.com) and port (995). `out` and `in` is the streams I write and read to/from.

One of the worst parts is that it doensn't throw any errors. Where I normally get the response, I just get an empty string.

Question is: How do I connect to a POP server over SSL/TLS, preferably the Gmail server?

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this:

```
public void connect() throws Exception {

    String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    Properties pop3Props = new Properties();

    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port",  "995");
    pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");

    URLName url = new URLName("pop3", "pop.gmail.com", 995, "",
            username, password);

    session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
    store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
    store.connect();

}
```

See this [article](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/javamail/connecting-gmail-using-pop3-connection-with-ssl-6.html) for more info.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using javax.mail.Message and javax.mail.Folder :/ but yes it works as it should, it just doesn't fit my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

declare socket s as SSLSocket . Then it will work

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.